udev problem is preventing Ubuntu upgrades
My server seems to be running fine, but any attempt at upgrade is aborting because of a problem with udev. It seems to boil down to the issue shown below, an "Exec format error" with systemd-udevd.service.
The same issue is reported in another post from 2+ years ago, but the solution seems to be specific to bionic, so I don't want to try that without being sure.
Grateful for any advice about this one, thanks.
Paul
#  lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

# systemctl status udev.service
● systemd-udevd.service - udev Kernel Device Manager
   Loaded: error (Reason: Exec format error)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-udevd.service(8)
           man:udev(7)

Jun 26 07:03:58 xxx.net systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit systemd-udevd.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
Jun 26 07:03:58 xxx.net systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0
Jun 26 07:03:58 xxx.net systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit systemd-udevd.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
Jun 26 07:04:10 xxx.net systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0
Jun 26 07:04:10 xxx.net systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit systemd-udevd.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
Jun 26 07:04:10 xxx.net systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0
Jun 26 07:04:10 xxx.net systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit systemd-udevd.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
Jun 26 07:04:10 xxx.net systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0
Jun 26 07:04:10 xxx.net systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit systemd-udevd.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
Jun 26 07:09:00 xxx.net systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit systemd-udevd.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
#
#
# grep -i exec /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
ExecReload=udevadm control --reload --timeout 0
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
# 
#
# ls -l /lib/systemd
total 7640
...
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    1314 Jun 23  2023 systemd-sysv-install
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   26688 Jun 23  2023 systemd-timedated
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   38976 Jun 23  2023 systemd-timesyncd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  760392 Nov 21  2023 systemd-udevd
...

Notice that systemd-udevd has a different date.  All the other systemd-* files are dated Jun 23.

Does this answer your question? Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 upgrade to 20.04 fails

What is the Exec (or ExecReload) line in the service file? In the linked answer, the issue could have been solved by correcting the path to the executable.

Thanks @Jos I updated the post with a few more details.  I'd really appreciate any suggestions you have.  Thanks.

Yes, that is the same problem as in the linked question. Replace udevadm with /usr/bin/udevadm and try again.

...unless the executable is located elsewhere. First, do which udevadm to make sure. It's /usr/bin/udevadm on my system though.
